# How to remove url from div using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How to remove or replace www.exaple.com/logos/rs-b.png from the background: url using css or java script

```
<div style="width:17px;height: 15px;background: url(//www.exaple.com/logos/rs-b.png) no-repeat right;background-size: contain;z-index: 1000;bottom: 1px;right: 1px;position: fixed;">
```

Comment: pls share code..

Comment: <div style="width:17px;height: 15px;background: url(//www.exaple.com/logos/rs-b.png) no-repeat right;background-size: contain;z-index: 1000;bottom: 1px;right: 1px;position: fixed;">

Comment: do u have any class for this div?

Comment: if u have any calss means .. you should add.. ie: .test{background:none}

Comment: no i dont have any class or id of div

Comment: try to add class and use background:none in css

Answer (score 0):

Without external libraries, you have two options. Both of these require you to add an ID or a class in order to identify the div. I'll use an ID:

```
<div id="custom-id" style="background: url('https://example.com')"></div>
```

### 1) Override the inline style with a CSS `!important` declaration:

You can add the following snippet in a `<style>` element or in an external stylesheet:

```
<style>
#custom-id {
    background: url('https://new-url.org') !important;
}
</style>
```

### 2) Use JavaScript to manipulate the inline style of the element:

You can do so with the built in DOM API of the browser, like so:

```
<script>
let div = document.getElementById('custom-id');
div.style.background = "url('https://new-url.org')";
</script>
```

### EDIT

After realizing you can't modify the HTML I came up with the following solution (that I already mentioned in the comments): Use the style attribute to identify the div. The answer above is still correct but with the exception that the CSS selector should change to match the style attribute:

```
div[style="width:17px;height: 15px;background: url(//www.exapl..."] {
    background: url('https://new-url.org') !important;
}
```

And the JS code too:

```
let div = document.querySelector('div[style="width:17px;height: 15px;background: url(//www.exapl..."]');
div.style.background = "url('https://new-url.org')";
```

While the best solution is to change the HTML, if you can't do that I think this is an acceptable solution that solves the problem.

Comment: i can add id or class due to its not hosted by me i am modifying third party code to hide background url –

Comment: Are u able to use jQuery?

Comment: If you can't modify the HTML, you could use the style attribute to identify the div (assuming it's not going to change): 
`document.querySelector('div[style="width:17px;height: 15px;background: url(//www.exaple.com/logos/rs-b.png) no-repeat right;background-size: contain;z-index: 1000;bottom: 1px;right: 1px;position: fixed;"]')`

Answer (score 0):

Find the  by using it's attribute and modify the style values

```
$('div.[style*="background:your_url"]).css('background', 'NewURL');
```